# ¿Cómo vuelvo a cargar el script de un slider? Al dar click a un botón cambian las imágenes pero deja de funcionar slider

Tags: javascript, html

Muchas gracias por su tiempo. Cuento con un slider (slick slider) y a su vez el código js para cambiar las imágenes del mismo al dar click a un botón, esto para cambiar la presentación del producto.

Les dejo el link del proyecto en github para poder verlo a detalle si desean: https://github.com/albertolr90/product-dinamic-slider.

El código de mi slider lo tengo declarado de la siguiente manera y funciona correctamente

```
<script src="plugins/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

El JS de mi botón con la acción `onclick="calabazapocopicante300()"` que cambia el contenido dentro de las etiquetas `<span id="calabazapocopicante">`:

```
<script src="plugins/slick/slick.min.js">
function calabazapocopicante300() {
    document.getElementById("calabazapocopicante").innerHTML ='código con las imágenes del producto y descripción de la presentación seleccionada';} 
</script>
```

Creo necesito insertar dentro de la función calabazapocopicante300 un código que vuelva a cargar el slider una vez que se cambia el contenido dentro de `<span id="calabazapocopicante">`.

Comment: Te recomiendo no uses los templates tan grandes, siendo que solo modificas 6 etiquetas. Solo modificas las url de las imagenes y la descripción. quisas si cambias un poco el codigo de la funcion para que solo cambie la url de las imagenes se solucione el problema de slider

Comment: Gracias, no puedo cambiar solo las imágenes ya que tengo que cambiar el título correspondiente a la presentación del producto, creo se puede apreciar mejor si observas su comportamiento en https://github.com/albertolr90/product-dinamic-slider

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Después, edita la pregunta de acuerdo a lo especificado en ambas publicaciones para que podamos ver aquí mismo tu problema en lugar de tener que estar buscando en un proyecto de github.

Comment: @AlbertoLr te lo comento por que lo vi, Eliminas toda la sección y la ingresas de nuevo para solo cambiar un par de atributos, te seria mas fácil cambiar solo el atributo que necesitas en vez de renderear toda la sección de nuevo y posiblemente elimine el bug que tiene al cambiar el producto

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios Ignacio, disculpa la demora en contestar pero me surgieron imprevistos, calculo el lunes poder seguir con el proyecto. En cuanto realice los cambios y lea los links que me proporcionaste me comunico para informarte. Que tengas una excelente noche, de nuevo, gracias.

Comment: Buenas tardes Ignacio, ya intenté realizar lo que me recomendaste pero no funcionó parcialmente, las imágenes en el thumbnail se dejan de mostrar pero si cambian en la vista principal